# Сравнение max & min

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int K[5][5];
    int i, j, max = 40, min = -20;
    int iMax = 0, jMax = 0, iMin = 0, jMin = 0;
   
//вывод
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            K[i][j] = min + rand() % (max + 1 - min);
            printf("%4d ", K[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
//сравнение
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (K[i][j] < K[iMin][jMin])
            {
                iMin = i;
                jMin = j;
            }
            if (K[i][j] > K[iMax][jMax])
            {
                iMax = i;
                jMax = j;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\t%d ",max,min );
   return  0;
   }
```

условие задания:Дана матрица А, состоящая из М строк и N столбцов. Элементами матрицы А являются натуральные числа. Н**азовем строку особой, если разность максимума и минимума по строке является простым числом. Вывести на экран количество особых строк**
Да знаю что не предоставил код,который пытался сделать по разделению строк(по правилам вроде нужно),но смысловой нагрузки от него ноль,потому что не чего не вышло.Прошу помочь

Comment: Вам нужно реализовать 2 функции -- `int is_prime (int num)`  (проверяет является ли `num` простым числом) и `void get_minmax (int row[], int n_cols, int *pmin, int *pmax)`  (возвращает по указателям `pmin` и `pmax` минимальное и максимальное значения в строке. Далее вы вызываете их для каждлй строки матрицы. Что-то типа `int cnt = 0; for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) { int mi, ma; get_minmax(&A[i][0], N, &mi, &ma); cnt += is_prime(ma - mi); }`

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/gTmOKW

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int M = 10, N = 20;
    int** K = malloc(M * sizeof(int*));

    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
        K[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(int));

        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) K[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        }

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) printf("%3d ", K[i][j]);

        printf("| ");
        int min = K[i][0], max = K[i][0];

        for (int j = 1; j < N; ++j) {
            if (min > K[i][j]) min = K[i][j];
            else if (max < K[i][j]) max = K[i][j];
            }

        int k = max - min;
        printf("%3d %3d %3d ", min, max, k);

        if (k == 0 || k == 1) continue;

        int prime = 1;

        for (int j = 2; j * j <= k; ++j) {
            if (k % j == 0) {
                prime = 0;
                break;
                }
            }

        if (prime) {
            printf("*\n");
            count++;
            }
        else printf("\n");
        }

    printf("\n%d\n", count);
    }
```